# qwinsta only returning headers when executed using PsExec in some scenarios

Tags: powershell, psexec

I have a problem with qwinsta only returning headers when executed using PsExec.

A minimal test case for this is to create a file "shelltest.ps1", containing just a single command (the last parameter to the qwista is the username but I get the same problem without it)

```
PSExec \\***.***.***.*** -u **** -p **** -accepteula qwinsta ****
```

When I excute this using file as input I get the right behavior

```
C:\>powershell.exe -Command .\shelltest.ps1

PsExec v2.0 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
 rdp-tcp#0         ****                     2  Active  rdpwd
qwinsta exited on ***.***.***.*** with error code 0.
```

but when I pipe in the command, I suddenly get only the header

```
C:\>powershell.exe -Command - < shelltest.ps1

PsExec v2.0 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
qwinsta exited on ***.***.***.*** with error code 0.
```

The real problem is a bit more complex, but an explanation on why this happens is hopefully sufficient enough to solve it.

Comment: Script files should be run using the `-File` parameter: `powershell.exe -File .\shelltest.ps1`. Also, the command from your second example never returns for me.

Comment: using -File gave the same response as running it as a command.

The pipe the command into stdin was because I noticed that was how TeamCity did it